# Responsive image inside bootstrap panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put an image inside a Bootstrap panel (attached image):

[image]

HTML Code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label> {{DisplayNickname}}</label>
            </div>
            <img src="{{DisplayPhoto}}" class="pull-right img-responsive" alt="user photo"> 
        </div>
        <font size="4" id=rating_d >Rating: </font>
        <font size="4" id=rating_d> {{DisplayRating | number : 2}}                        </font>
        <br><br>
        <font size="4">Description:</font>
        <font size="4" id=details>{{DisplayDescription}}</font>

    </div> 
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

It's working with `position:absolute`, but it's not responsive. What is the right way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried using percentages?

Comment: Nope, what do you mean?

Comment: Try doing width as 10% and height:auto.

Comment: Its the same result if i put 50px, 50px..

Comment: Don't use the `<font>` tag

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will work

```
<img src="{{DisplayPhoto}}" class="pull-right img-responsive" alt="user photo" width="150">
```

if this not work try this

```
 <div style="width:150px;"><img src="{{DisplayPhoto}}" class="pull-right img-responsive" alt="user photo" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the image in a grid column too?

```
<div class="panel panel-default col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <label> {{DisplayNickname}}</label>
            </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <img src="//placehold.it/200" class="pull-right img-responsive" alt="user photo"> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <font size="4" id=rating_d >Rating: </font>
        <font size="4" id=rating_d> {{DisplayRating | number : 2}}</font>
        <br><br>
        <font size="4">Description:</font>
        <font size="4" id=details>{{DisplayDescription}}</font>
    </div> 
</div>
```

http://bootply.com/dj5qbgC2Kf

Also, HTML font tag is deprecated (Just FYI)